# How can you mask a UIImage with a UIControl?

Tags: ios, swift, mask, uiswitch, uicontrol

I can set a UIImage's mask property to another UIView, but if I set the UIImage's mask property to a UISwitch, the UIImage and UISwitch does not display.

```
    recordMicSwitch = UISwitch()
    guard let sc = recordMicSwitch else { return }
    sc.frame = CGRect(x: deviceWidth - sc.frame.size.width - rightMargin, y: yPos, width: 0, height: 0)
    sc.onTintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.717, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    view.addSubview(sc)

    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "testBGGradient.png")!
    let bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
    bgImage.frame = CGRect(x:200, y:120, width:bgImage.frame.width/2, height:bgImage.frame.height/2)
    bgImage.mask = recordMicSwitch!
    self.view.addSubview(bgImage)
```

Comment: Just a note - I can't update the post without getting the spinning ball on my computer for every character I input.

Comment: `sc.frame = CGRect(x: deviceWidth - sc.frame.size.width - rightMargin` <- does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I should have left out those details. It's not a matter of placement. It's in the correct place, I just don't think UIControls are supported by mask properties.

Comment: Why are you setting the mask to `recordMicSwitch!`, and not `sc` ?

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie - you certainly *can* use a control such as `UISwitch` as a mask for another view, but you're doing a couple things wrong (for one, you cannot change the frame of a switch in that manner). However, the question is, what are you really trying to do? Do you want your image to be masked by the visual appearance of the switch? Or are you trying to use the image to apply a gradient to the switch itself?

Comment: I'm trying to apply a gradient to the switch itself. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717378/is-there-a-blending-mode-or-something-else-i-can-set-for-uicontrols-so-that-i-ca/54771187?noredirect=1#comment96324363_54771187

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie So does the answer you linked not work?

Comment: It works, just not a mask.

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie - OK, what you've tried so far ends up using the "visible" part of a `UISwitch` as a mask for an image view... but you want the other-way-around. I doubt you can accomplish that without using a custom switch. Take a quick search for `custom uiswitch` ... lots of options. If you can't find one that gives you what you want, at least you'll have good starting points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this actually isn't as simple as just masking our image to the `UISwitch`.

The reason this simple approach won't work is because of how masking actually works. When we mask an image like you're suggesting, we take the shape of another view and apply it to our image. Then, our image is actually added to the parent. What we end up with is an image that is cut to the shape of our switch (this image receives none of the switch events).

What we actually have to do is a little more involved. We need to add our image to different parts of the switch's `subview`s, and mask to those instead.

**For convenience, I made a custom switch class that does the heavy-lifting behind the scenes:**

```
class ImageTintSwitch: UISwitch {

    init(tintImage: UIImage) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        // Make sure we have subviews & grab the first one
        guard let element = subviews.first else { return }

        // Loop through only the subviews that clipToBounds inside the one we grabbed
        for (index, view) in element.subviews.enumerated() where view.clipsToBounds {

            // Add our image only where we need it
            configure(with: tintImage, on: element, maskedTo: view, atIndex: index)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func configure(with image: UIImage, on parent: UIView, maskedTo view: UIView, atIndex index: Int) {
        // Make an imageView with our image
        let imageView: UIImageView = {
            let view = UIImageView(image: image)
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return view
        }()

        // Insert our new imageView only where we need it
        parent.insertSubview(imageView, at: index)

        // Mask our imageView to the views that we found
        imageView.mask = view

        // Constrain our imageView to match the parent view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.centerXAnchor),
            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.centerYAnchor),
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.widthAnchor),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.heightAnchor)
            ])
    }
}
```

**To use this custom switch, we can just use the following code:**

```
let customSwitch = ImageTintSwitch(tintImage: UIImage(named: "gradient.jpg") ?? UIImage())
```

**Here's the result:**

[image: Switch GIF]